# Android PJSIP ndk-build issue No such file or directory

Tags: pjsip

I am developing android app using PJSIP. I have successfully installed required     softwares and executed almost all the commands given in PJSIP android - getting started page. But I got stuck while executing command "ndk-build". 
I followed the below link:
"http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android"
It is giving following error. (Platform used: Windows + Cygwin)

```
$ ndk-build
Invoking SWIG...
swig -c++ -o jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir src/org/pjsip/p
jsua -java jni/pjsua.i
Compile++ thumb  : pjsua <= pjsua_wrap.cpp
In file included from jni/../../pjsua_app.h:27:0,
                 from jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp:414:
jni/../../pjsua_app_common.h:22:29: fatal error: pjsua-lib/pjsua.h: No such file
 or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/d/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-binary.mk:272: recipe for
 target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/pjsua/pjsua_wrap.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/pjsua/pjsua_wrap.o] Error 1
```

I think, problem is with path as pjsua.h is not present in pjsua-lib folder.
But I have tried almost all paths, but no luck. 
Any help related to this will be appreciated.

Comment: I am able to build this project using Linux without any problem. Previously facing this issue using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Before performing ndk-build command, please do the following steps

cd pjsip-apps/build
make pjsua

then perform ndk-build in /pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android directory

Comment: I have done same thing using Linux platform and my problem is solved. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Datroid can you help me with jni/pjsua_wrap.cpp:710:52: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
       throw Swig::DirectorException(jenv, swigerror);